# How to properly set a SUM AGGREGATE on a group-level column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS report, and I'm trying to sum one of the columns.

[image]

The first column is a countdistinct(field1) and works perfectly.

The second column is in the same group as the first.  When the first expands, the second column is part of the first group.

I'm trying to get the value here 24 in the group total.
if I perform a `[SUM(CDEC(FIELD2.value))]` it results in `72` because technically the 12 is repeated through all six records.

`[SUM(MAX(FIELD2.value))]` results in a `12`, because the `MAX()` function gives max value of ALL the records.

How do I get 24, here?

Thanks

UPDATE #1.
here's the field setup for those columns
[image]

[image]

Someone mentioned using a scope in my sum().  How do I determine what my scope is?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some example records?

Comment: those are the example records in the image.

Comment: the image shows the exact output.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc. for the database backend?

Comment: That I can answer....MS SQL Server 2016 SSRS

Comment: The other option is to calculate the value in SQL with using `SUM OVER PARTITION`.

Comment: can that be mimic'd in MDX?

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it....it is already there, because technically there's 6x 12's in the output, and the report format (rdl) sets the group, yes?

Comment: You can also nest the tablix within each other and in the parent tablix do the grouping.

Comment: right on....I'll look up how to do that.

Comment: Using a "scope" parameter will not be helpful, you only need that if you want to use a *larger* scope, in your case, there is no larger scope because you already are on the report level. Nesting tablixes will also not be helpful, because nested tablixes all use the same dataset which in your case contains the details (ServiceCategory). These details are the disturbing point. You need a second dataset that does not contain the details. Oh, and `SUM OVER` will also not work because of the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the scope in the sum expression in your tablix otherwise it always takes the dataset data. Let´s say you have a dataset (**Dataset1**), with the fields **SalesOrder**, **SalesPrice**. If you group now in your tablix by **SalesOrder** (**GroupingBySalesOrder**) you can add different scopes for the aggregate functions:

```
=Sum(Fields!SalesPrice.Value) 'This takes the Default scope "Dataset1"
=Sum(Fields!SalesPrice.Value, "Dataset1") 'The same result like above
=Sum(Fields!SalesPrice.Value, "GroupingBySalesOrder") 'The scope is now your grouping. Different result like the other two
```

Comment: This is awesome. Groupbysalesorder in your example.  Is that the tablix textbox name, or a predefined construction of terms i assemble?  Ie. Grouping by is the lambda and salesorder is the dataset field?

Comment: When you click on your tablix you have (on the bottom left) the **Row Groups** with the **(Details)** drop down. Click on the **(Details)** drop down and chose **Add group > Parent group**. Now chose the field for the grouping (you can also add a group header) and hit OK. Below the **(Details)** drop down appears your new group and there is the name for your grouping. This name can you use as scope in a tablix textbox expression (like in the post above).